# Trying to extract a string of text pattern from the beginning and the end of a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, string, text, excel-formula, extract

I have the following data and what I would like to see on the column result:

| Data | Result |
| --- | --- |
| PN 65011:2020text text text PN 65011:2020 | PN 65011:2020, PN 65011:2020 |
| PN 45014-1:2017text text text text PN 65014-1:2017 PN 8726-1:2017/P11:2020 | PN 45014-1:2017, PN 65014-1:2017, PN 8726-1:2017/P11:2020 |
| PN 6534:2020text text text text | PN 6534:2020 |
| PN 65014-1:2017text text text text PN 65014-1:2017/PC1:2013 | PN 65014-1:2017,PN 65014-1:2017/PC1:2013 |
| PN ESO 67345:2019text text text PN 65018-1:2019/PC2:2020 | PN ESO 67345:2019, PN 65018-1:2019/PC2:2020 |
| PN ESO/EOC 5320:2013text text text PN ESO 27380:2019 PN 65015-1:2020/PC:2021 | PN ESO/EOC 5320:2013, PN ESO 27380:2019, PN 65015-1:2020/PC:2021 |

I have used `="PN "&TEXTJOIN(", PN ",1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"PN ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))*LEN(A2)-(LEN(A2)-1),LEN(A2))))),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"PN ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))*LEN(A2)-(LEN(A2)-1),LEN(A2))),LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"PN ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))*LEN(A2)-(LEN(A2)-1),LEN(A2))),MIN(IFERROR(FIND({" "},LOWER(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"PN ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))*LEN(A2)-(LEN(A2)-1),LEN(A2))))),""))-1)))`

And I almost get what I would like to see, except for the last row (PN ESO 5320:2013), I don't get the numbers. It stops at PN ESO. Like this:

| Data | Result |
| --- | --- |
| PN ESO/EOC 5320:2013text text PN ESO 27380:2019 text PN 65015-1:2020/PC:2021 | PN ESO/EOC, PN ESO |

Any ideas on how I can get the entire reference?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There is no space between the first reference and the text and for the other ones, there is always space. The "text text text" are titles of the references that vary in length and they are not relevant enough to be extracted because if I know the reference I will be able to retrieve them in the database. It's O365.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how you could approach this using Excel O365

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"PN ","</s><s>PN ")&"</s></t>","//s[position() > 1]"),Y,LEFT(X,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(X,":","|",LEN(X)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(X,":",""))))+4),Y))
```

The idea here is to first `SUBSTITUTE()` all instances of "PN " to a valid xpath construct. Then we using `FILTERXML()` to return all values as an array, obviously still with the concatenated "text text text". Therefor I used `LET()` to load the array as a variable and use some string manipulation on all elements.

First I substituted the last occurence of the colon in all strings into a pipe-symbol which we then `FIND()` and return its position. Now we have the positions we can extract the the proper substrings using `LEFT()`. Used `TEXTJOIN()` to join the resulting array back together.

Comment: +1, just one minor thing you have put `A7` instead of `A2` in the formula. Copied from wrong cell I suppose :)

Comment: I get an error. It doesn't seem to work with the original dataset, the one where I have the real titles for the references. Do I need to do anything for the FILTERXML or it should naturally work on a O365 workbook?

Comment: It should naturally work (unless you are using Excel Online or Excel Mac) @Jas

Comment: I get a #NAME error in the LET bit of the formula.

Comment: I am using Excel locally from Office 365 and it's Windows.

Comment: Looks like `LET` is not generally available yet.  [From Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) _Note: This is one of several beta features, and currently only available to a portion of Office Insiders at this time. We'll continue to optimize these features over the next several months. When they're ready, we'll release them to all Office Insiders, and Microsoft 365 subscribers._

Comment: @chrisneilsen, thanks for the contribution. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept a VBA solution, regular expressions are well suited for this kind of problem.  If your examples are all as you show:

We use the regex which will look for substrings that

- start with PN
- pick up the following characters until we end with a colon followed by multiple digits.
- if there is a `/` following, then look for the next set up to colon-multiple digit pattern.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `<alt-F11>` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select **Insert/Module** and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=extrPN(cell_Ref)` in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function extrPN(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Const sPat As String = "PN[^:]+:\d+(?:/[^:]+:\d+)?"
    Dim sTemp As String
    
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    .ignorecase = False
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
            For Each M In MC
                sTemp = sTemp & ", " & M
            Next M
            extrPN = Mid(sTemp, 3)
    Else: extrPN = "no match"
    End If
End With
End Function
```

[image]

Explanation of Regex

**extract PN**

```
PN.*?:\d+(?:/[^:]+:\d+)?
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Match the character string “PN” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `PN`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*?`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `*?`
- [Match the colon character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `:`
- [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:/[^:]+:\d+)?`

  - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match the character “/” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `/`
  - [Match any character that is NOT the colon character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[^:]+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match the colon character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `:`
  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)